Cannot display as a guest user in ecommerce site in Python+Django
I was following a YouTube tutorial of Dennis Ivy,(https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-51WBLyFTg0omnamUjL1TCVov7yDTRng), where number of items in "cart-icon" and total amount information is rendered.
Image of how it should be: correct_rendering
Image of how it is: error_rendering
In my case, those are not rendered. I am not sure what went wrong. I tried to search the issue in chatGpt, but couldn't solve the problem. Below is my code:
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json
from .models import *
import datetime
 
def store(request): 
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items  # Corrected: Call the method to get cart items
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total': 0, 'get_cart_items': 0, 'shipping': False}
        cartItems = order['get_cart_items']
 
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products': products, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)
 
def cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        # total = sum(item.product.price * item.quantity for item in items)
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items  # Corrected: Call the method to get cart items
    else:
        try:
            cart = json.loads(request.COOKIES['cart'])  # Use .get() to avoid KeyError
            # cart = json.loads(request.COOKIES.get('cart', '{}'))  # Use .get() to avoid KeyError
        except :
        # json.JSONDecodeError:
            cart = {}  # If decoding fails, initialize an empty dictionary
 
        # Initialize items as an empty list for guest users
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total': 0, 'get_cart_items': 0, 'shipping': False}
        # Initialize cartItems to 0 before the loop
        cartItems = order['get_cart_items']
 
        # For guests, update the cart items based on the cookie data
        for i in cart:
            cartItems += cart[i]['quantity']  # Use .get() to avoid KeyError
 
 
            # # Increment cartItems by the quantity of the current item
            # cartItems += cart[i].get('quantity', 0)  # Use .get() to avoid KeyError
            # product = Product.objects.get(id=i)
            # total = (product.price * cart[i].get('quantity', 0))  # Fix typo in 'quantity'
 
            # order['get_cart_total'] += total
            # order['get_cart_items'] += cart[i].get("quantity", 0)  # Fix typo in 'quantity'
            # item = {  # Define item here
            #     'product': 
            #     {
            #         'id': product.id,
            #         'name': product.name,
            #         'price': product.price,
            #         'imageURL': product.imageURL,
            #     },
            #     'quantity': cart[i].get("quantity", 0),  # Use .get() to avoid KeyError
            #     'get_total': total
            # }
            # items.append(item)  # Append item to items list here
 
    context = {'items': items, 'order': order, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    return render(request, "store/cart.html", context)
 
def checkout(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        if created:  # Save the order if it's newly created
            order.save()
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        total = order.get_cart_total()  # Call the method to get cart total
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items()  # Call the method to get cart items
    else:
        order = Order()  # Dummy Order object
        order.save()  # Save the order
        items = []
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items # Call the method to get cart items
 
    context = {'items': items, 'order': order, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    return render(request, "store/checkout.html", context)
 
 
 
def processOrder(request):
    transaction_id = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    data= json.loads(request.body)
    # parse the data
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        total = float(data['total'])  # Assuming 'total' is directly in 'data' dictionary
        order.transaction_id = transaction_id
 
        if total == float(order.get_cart_items()):  # Corrected: Method name and variable usage
            order.complete = True
        order.save()
 
        if order.shipping == True:
            # Assuming correct structure of form data, adjust as needed
            ShippingAddress.objects.create(
                customer=customer,
                order=order,
                address=data['shipping']['address'],
                city=data['shipping']['city'],
                state=data['shipping']['state'],
                zipcode=data['shipping']['zipcode']
            )
    else:
        print("user is not logged in...")
    return JsonResponse('payment complete', safe=False)
 
 
 
def updateItem(request):
    # post request we are sending
    data= json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
 
    print('action:',action)
    print('productId:',productId)
 
    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
 
    orderItem, created= OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)
 
    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity= (orderItem.quantity + 1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity=(orderItem.quantity - 1)
 
    orderItem.save()
 
    if orderItem.quantity<=0:
        orderItem.delete()
 
    return JsonResponse('Item was added',safe=False)

models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=200)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name if self.name else "Unnamed Customer"
 
 
 
class Product(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
        price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2)
        digital=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=True)#if false its a physicall product needed to be deliverd or shipped
        image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
        #yespachi matra media root define garmne ho
        #mediaroot le panel bata haleko lai tyo directory ma pyuraucha
 
        def __str__(self):
             return self.name
 
        @property
        def imageURL(self):
             try:
                  url = self.image.url
             except:
                  url= ''
             return url
          #to solve image problem of not adding one
 
class Order(models.Model):
     customer= models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank= True) 
    #  many to one relation that is a customer can have more order
     date_ordered=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     complete=models.BooleanField(default=False)
     transaction_id=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
 
     def __str__(self):
          return str(self.id)
 
     @property
     def shipping(self):
          shipping= False
          # query orderitem
          orderitems=self.orderitem_set.all()
          for i in orderitems:
               if i.product.digital== False:
                    shipping=True
          return shipping
 
     @property
     def get_cart_total(self):
          orderitems= self.orderitem_set.all()
          total= sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
          return total
 
     @property
     def get_cart_items(self):
          orderitems= self.orderitem_set.all()
          total= sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
          return total
 
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 
    @property
    def get_total(self):
         total=self.product.price * self.quantity
         return total
 
 
class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
     customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
     #even if the order is deleted we can still have shipping adress
     order=models.ForeignKey(Order , on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
     address=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
     city=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
     state=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
     zipcode=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
     date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 
     def __str__(self):
          return self.address

cart.js
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("update-cart");
 
for (var i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
  updateBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    var productId = this.dataset.product;
    var action = this.dataset.action;
    console.log("productId:", productId, "action:", action);
 
    if (user === "AnonymousUser") {
        addCookieItem(productId, action);
    } else {
        updateUserOrder(productId, action);
    }
  });
}
 
function addCookieItem(productId, action) {
    console.log("Not logged in");
 
    if (action === "add") {
      if (cart[productId] === undefined) {
        cart[productId] = { quantity: 1 };
      } else {
        cart[productId]["quantity"] += 1;
      }
    }
    if (action === "remove") {
      cart[productId]["quantity"] -= 1;
      if (cart[productId]["quantity"] <= 0) {
        console.log("Remove Item");
        delete cart[productId];
      }
    }
    console.log("cart:", cart);
    document.cookie = "cart=" + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";domain=;path=/";
    location.reload(true);
}
 
function updateUserOrder(productId, action) {
  console.log("user is logged in, sending data...");
  var url = "/update_item/";
 
  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ productId: productId, action: action }),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("data:", data);
      location.reload(true);
    });
}

main.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ecom</title>
 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var user='{{request.user}}'
// csrf to prevent from attack in the backend like fund transefr and all
        function getToken(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getToken('csrftoken');
 
function getCookie(name){
    var cookieArr=document.cookie.split(";");
    // loop throough the array element
    for(var i=0;i< cookieArr.length;i++){
        var cookiePair= cookieArr[i].split("=");
 
        if(name==cookiePair[0].trim()){
            return decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[1]);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
 
var cart=JSON.parse(getCookie('cart'))
if(cart == undefined){
    cart={}
    console.log('cart waas created')
    document.cookie='cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";domain=;path=/"
}
console.log('cart:',cart)
    </script>
<!-- so that geust cookie also can be generated -->
</head>
<body>
 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'store' %}">Ecom</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
 
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'store' %}">Store <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
 
        </ul>
        <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <a href="#"class="btn btn-warning">Login</a>
 
            <a href="{% url 'cart' %}">
                <img  id="cart-icon" src="{% static 'images/cart.png' %}">
            </a>
            <p id="cart-total">{{cartItems}}</p>
 
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
 
     <div class="container">
            <br>
            {% block content %}
 
 
            {% endblock content %}
         </div>
 
 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/cart.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>

